# How can I use mysql functions when I use collection filters?

Tags: magento2, database, collection

How can I use something like this one `NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY` in collection filter?

```
->addFieldToFilter('period', ['gteq' => 'NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY'])
```

Before running the query, the value in the filter is going to be converted into a string, so MySQL will not run it as functions.

Is there any way I can use the MySql functions in a filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using a `Zend_Db_Expr` object.

```
->addFieldToFilter('period', ['gteq' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY')])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$collection->getSelect()->where("period >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY");
```

But make sure correct sql syntax passed inside where function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$whereClause = " status = 'processing' and created_at < (TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE, -30, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))";

$collection->getSelect()-> where($whereClause);
```

Comment: It could be helpful to explain your answer as the many people reading your answer may have various background. Now, your answer has a syntax error that I can see and this will give you negative feedback. thanks for your answer and your understanding